# GWT library for indexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, web, indexeddb

Is there a GWT library for HTML5 `indexedDB` functionality?

Or, alternatively, is there a Javascript one I could wrap for GWT?

Comment: If you're going to wrap some JS, why not just wrap indexedDB API; there's no need for an intermediate JS library!

Comment: the JS library is for educational purpose only - I would definitely go with JSNI on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to write it with JSNI but it was useless because of the lack of support by browsers and different "strange" behaviors. Then I emulate is by using java Maps it has some essence of the indexedDB but not perfect solution

also now there is http://code.google.com/p/indexeddb-gwt which seems to be promising

Answer (score 0):

There is a project on Google Code, but it looks like there is nothing there. You might want to contact its owner and ask what the state of the project is:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-indexeddb/

Or just role on your own using JSNI...